# Can I draw a polygon with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having some problems finding any good documentation, so I thinking its not possible... but is there a way to draw a polygon with Xamarin.Forms?

Xamarin.Forms.View seems not to have the same implementation as Android.Views.View :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not using the in-built views; the most sophisticated shape XF natively supports right now is a box. However, a custom view with native renderers for your target platforms could.

Answer (score 0):

At best you can start a native activity and then use standard android paradigms

To start, call the following from your XF view model (or view):
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity (typeof(MyNativeActivity));

Where `MyNativeActivity` is your native activity that draws on the screen.